Serializing and Deserializing XPC objects (xpc_object_t)
As the title suggests, I am interested in serializing/deserializing xpc_object_t type objects. Unfortunately, there does not seem to be an official or private API that supports this in a robust fashion.
I came accross the private functions:
xpc_object_t _CFXPCCreateXPCMessageWithCFObject(CFTypeRef)
CFTypeRef _CFXPCCreateCFObjectFromXPCMessage(xpc_object_t)
To my understanding, these functions should represent exactly what I am looking for. However, the resulting Dictionary is nil, suggesting that the objects can't be serialized. Initially I thought, maybe this does not work for nested Dictionaries. Unfortunatelly, a testcase with a very simple Dictionary resulted in nil as well.
Since these are private functions, there does not seem to be any (public) useful information available. Is there anything that I am missing?
Thank you.

Does it need to be an Apple API? There are a lot of projects with XPC implementations (parsing and sometimes generating). Alternatively you could try to identify the library those functions are implemented in and decompile them using Ghidra, IDA or a similar tool.

Hi Robert, no it does not need to be Apple. I would actually prefer a robust, pure C implementation. All I would like to do is to store an xpc object to a file. I was looking at potential Apple API's because I assumed, that Apple would surely provide such an API.
